# Invalid datatype when adding constraint in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I want to create this table in Oracle. This is only the table SQL script.

```
     -- CREATE TABLES SECTION -------------------------------------------------

-- TABLE DATACENTER

CREATE TABLE DATACENTER(
  DATACENTERID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(80 ) NOT NULL,
  LOCATION VARCHAR2(200 ),
  DCALLOWEDWEIGHTKG NUMBER(9,0),
  DCMAXIMUMWEIGHTKG NUMBER(9,0),
  DCALLOWEDPOWERWATT NUMBER(9,0),
  DCMAXPOWERWATT NUMBER(9,0),
  DCALLOWCOOLINGPOWERBTU NUMBER(9,0),
  DCMAXCOOLINGPOWERBTU NUMBER(9,0),
  DESCRIPTION CLOB
)
/
-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE DATACENTER

ALTER TABLE DATACENTER ADD CONSTRAINT DATACENTERID PRIMARY KEY (DATACENTERID)
/

-- TABLE COMPONENT

CREATE TABLE COMPONENT(
  COMPONENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  DATACENTERID INTEGER,
  FKCOMPONENTID INTEGER,
  COMPONENTSTATSID INTEGER NOT NULL
)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE COMPONENT

ALTER TABLE COMPONENT ADD CONSTRAINT COMPONENTID PRIMARY KEY (COMPONENTID)
/
-- CREATE RELATIONSHIPS SECTION ------------------------------------------------- 

ALTER TABLE COMPONENT ADD CONSTRAINT IS PART OF A FOREIGN KEY (DATACENTERID) REFERENCES DATACENTER (DATACENTERID)
/

ALTER TABLE COMPONENT ADD CONSTRAINT IS A SUBPART OF FOREIGN KEY (FKCOMPONENTID) REFERENCES COMPONENT (COMPONENTID)
/
```

The error stack:

```
table DATACENTER created.
table DATACENTER altered.
table COMPONENT created.
table COMPONENT altered.

Error starting at line 39 in command:
ALTER TABLE COMPONENT ADD CONSTRAINT IS PART OF A FOREIGN KEY (DATACENTERID) REFERENCES DATACENTER (DATACENTERID)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line 42 in command:
ALTER TABLE COMPONENT ADD CONSTRAINT IS A SUBPART OF FOREIGN KEY (FKCOMPONENTID) REFERENCES COMPONENT (COMPONENTID)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

**EDIT** I edited the code because I saw that some SQL statements are missing.
I can provide the schema if you want?

Best wishes

Comment: Again: you are using invalid names for your constraints (`IS PART OF A` and `IS A SUBPART OF`). You must **NOT** use a space in the constraint's name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your constraint name `IS PART OF A` is an illegal identifier (because of the spaces).

You need to remove the spaces, e.g. `IS_PART_OF_A`:

```
ALTER TABLE COMPONENT 
   ADD CONSTRAINT IS_PART_OF_A 
   FOREIGN KEY (DATACENTERID) 
   REFERENCES DATACENTER (DATACENTERID)
```

**Edit**
I also realized that your script is not correctly terminating the individual statements. There is a `;` (or `/`)  missing after the first CREATE TABLE. And the first `ALTER TABLE` is not properly terminated as well. I don't know if that is a copy & paste error though.

**Edit2**:

Here is the complete script with correct names, statement termination and in the correct order:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPONENT(
    COMPONENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DATACENTERID INTEGER,
    FKCOMPONENTID INTEGER,
    COMPONENTSTATSID INTEGER NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE TABLE DATACENTER(
  DATACENTERID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(80 ) NOT NULL,
  LOCATION VARCHAR2(200 ),
  DCALLOWEDWEIGHTKG NUMBER(9,0),
  DCMAXIMUMWEIGHTKG NUMBER(9,0),
  DCALLOWEDPOWERWATT NUMBER(9,0),
  DCMAXPOWERWATT NUMBER(9,0),
  DCALLOWCOOLINGPOWERBTU NUMBER(9,0),
  DCMAXCOOLINGPOWERBTU NUMBER(9,0),
  DESCRIPTION CLOB
)
/

ALTER TABLE DATACENTER ADD CONSTRAINT DATACENTERID PRIMARY KEY (DATACENTERID)
/

ALTER TABLE COMPONENT ADD CONSTRAINT COMPONENTID PRIMARY KEY (COMPONENTID)
/

ALTER TABLE COMPONENT ADD CONSTRAINT IS_PART_OF_A FOREIGN KEY (DATACENTERID) REFERENCES DATACENTER (DATACENTERID)
/
```

Comment: @PeterPenzov: TDM doesn't invent the constraint names on its own. It uses the ones you have entered.

Comment: I created the tables and then I add the constraints.